# ACEDAO DbEngine available from Access but not from .NET

Tags: .net, ms-access, com

My .NET application is working with MS Access databases and using "Microsoft Access database engine Data Access Object Library" (ACEDAO.DLL) to read database. But it works only if I install Microsoft Access Database Engine. My goal is to avoid it. For example - currently I have Office 2013 x64 with Access installed and it does not work.

If I add COM reference and/or use Microsoft.Office.Interop.Access.Dao.dll - it fails with COMException CLSID {CD7791B9-43FD-42C5-AE42-8DD2811F0419} not registered.

If I try to use late binding with Type.GetTypeFromProgID("DAO.DBEngine.120") - it returns null.

Does not matter how I build application - AnyCPU, x86, x64 - it does not work.

At the same time, on the same computer, if I do the same things from Access - it works! I can do both

```
Set dbe = New DBEngine
Set db = dbe.OpenDatabase(filePath)
```

and

```
Set dbe = CreateObject("DAO.DBEngine.120")
Set db = dbe.OpenDatabase(filePath)
```

it does not fail.

Please don't suggest to install Microsoft Access Database Engine or Access Runtime. That's not what I am searching for. I am just try to understand why something available from Access is not available from more powerful .NET and how can I fix this without need to install anything else?

Comment: .NET maybe powerful but it still needs a driver to talk to a database. You can't use an Access database w/o installing Access itself or Access Redistributable or Runtime. Without one of them, you can only use the old MDB/Jet4 database with .NET w/o a specific driver. There's no way around this.

Comment: @SimonMourier I have installed Access

Comment: You said you want to avoid installing Access. Please clarify your question.

Comment: @SimonMourier I said to avoid installation of Microsoft Access Database Engine or Access Runtime - that's different separate installation packages that can be downloaded from MS. For example first one can be taken here https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13255. If I install it .NET code starts to work. My goal is to make it work without need of installation of anything else apart from Microsoft Access

Comment: Ok got it. Do you use Office Click-To-Run: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/expression/en-US/5f0f8178-0943-4c21-855b-2ecff489c97e/why-cant-i-cocreateinstance-a-daodbengine120-object-access-2016?forum=vclanguage ? In this case, it may not be possible as Access lives in its own "bubble". ACEDAO.dll is installed  but configured in a part of the registry that makes it invisible outside of its own process.

Comment: @SimonMourier, thanks a lot - this may be an explanation, yes. I've searched for 'DAO.DBEngine.120' in registry and I see that it is under ClickToRun path. But in this case it is not clear why I can connect to 'Access.Application' from .NET which I suppose should be in "bubble" as well. In any way this may be the route for further digging for me. Thanks for your time!

Comment: Can you try this program and see if it works on a machine with only Access installed? https://gist.github.com/smourier/0b85ab1336c0e3e3f15a75315cc6fe63

Comment: @SimonMourier thanks a lot for your code but it does not work yet. Once I fix registry path and run as x64 - it is able to read engineClsid and acedaoPath but it looks like it is some kind of virtual path inside the bubble. I see the same path in Access ACEDAO reference properties, but it does not exist. Moreover even if I try to use proper path by putting it before LoadLibrary call - x64 fails on LoadLibrary, and x86 returns IntPtr.Zero with GetLastWin32Error = 1008. I was trying to check what it does with Process Monitor but no luck, looks like I don't have enough knowldge about win internls

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out that answer was just to wait for 3 years. As Simon has mentioned in comments to my question - ACE/DAO libraries were "in the bubble", available for Office but not for external app. And finally in 2020 MS decided to make them available again:
[Breaking ACE Out Of The Bubble](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/access-blog/breaking-ace-out-of-the-bubble/bc-p/1168784)